# Play 2.6 Silhouette compose SecuredAction

Tags: scala, playframework, silhouette

I am trying to do something really similar to [this](http://discourse.silhouette.rocks/t/extending-securedrequest-with-actionrefiner/167/2). `ContextRequest` and `ContextAction`. I have a `securedRequest` from `Silhouette` and I want to compose an `Action` reading a `cookie` I set up.

the difference is that I extended the `User` from Silhouette `Identity`

`DataSourceRequest`

```
class DataSourceRequest[DefaultEnv, B](
  val dataSource: Option[String],
  val securedRequest: SecuredRequest[DefaultEnv, B]
) extends WrappedRequest[B](securedRequest.request) {
  def user: User = securedRequest.identity
  def requestV: Request[B] = securedRequest.request
}
```

`DataSourceAction`

```
class DataSourceAction @Inject()
  (val parser: BodyParsers.Default)(implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext)
  extends ActionRefiner[({ type R[B] = SecuredRequest[DefaultEnv, B] })#R, ({ type R[B] = DataSourceRequest[DefaultEnv, B] })#R] {

  override protected def refine[A](securedRequest: SecuredRequest[DefaultEnv, A]) = Future.successful {
    try {
      Right(new DataSourceRequest[DefaultEnv, A](
        securedRequest.session.get("dataSource").getOrElse("dataSourceMissing"),
        securedRequest
      ))
    } catch {
      case _: Exception => Left(Results.NotFound)
    }
  }
}
```

`DefaultEnv`

```
trait DefaultEnv extends Env {
  type I = User
  type A = CookieAuthenticator
}
```

I am not able to get the `User` because

> (Note that com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Identity does not match models.User: class User in package entities is a subclass of trait Identity in package api, but method parameter types must match exactly.)

I know that probably I am missing a wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving a context bound to your `Env`, like this:

```
class DataSourceRequest[Env <: DefaultEnv, B](
  val dataSource: Option[String],
  val securedRequest: SecuredRequest[Env, B]
) extends WrappedRequest[B](securedRequest.request) {
  def user: User = securedRequest.identity
  def requestV: Request[B] = securedRequest.request
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added some functionality in a pull request that should do the same thing https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-seed/pull/118